# Syntax error in My sqlite when i add a new table

Tags: android, syntax-error, android-sqlite

Now,i'm add a new table to sqlitedatabase and change a databae_version from 1 to version 2 (my new table is category)
this is my code in BooksDBHelper

```
package com.example.mutitablesql.db;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class BooksDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
//databse_name
public static String DATABSE_NAME = "bookguk";
// database_version
public static int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
//table name
public static String TABLE_BOOK = "books";
public static String TABLE_IMAGE = "images";
public static String TABLE_INGREDIENT = "ingredients";
public static String TABLE_CATEGORY = "category";
//column_name
public static String KEY_ID = "id";
public static String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static String KEY_SOLUTION = "solution";
public static String KEY_BOK_ID = "bookID";
public static String KEY_fILEPATH = "filepath";
public static String KEY_VALUE = "value" ;
public static String KEY_UNIT = "unit";
public static String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static String KEY_CAT_ID = "cat_id";

public static String BOOK_CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_BOOK + "(" +
                                ""+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                                ""+KEY_TITLE+" TEXT(50) not null," +
                                ""+KEY_SOLUTION+" TEXT(255) not null," +
                                ""+KEY_CAT_ID+" INTEGER(11)," +
                                " FOREIGN KEY("+KEY_CAT_ID+") REFERENCE "+TABLE_CATEGORY+" ("+KEY_ID+"))";

public static String IMAGE_CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_IMAGE + "(" +
                                ""+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                                ""+KEY_fILEPATH+" VACHAR(255)," +
                                ""+KEY_BOK_ID+" INTEGER(11)," +
                                " FOREIGN KEY("+KEY_BOK_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_BOOK+" ("+KEY_ID+"))";

public static String INGREDIENT_CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_INGREDIENT + "(" +
                                ""+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                                ""+KEY_VALUE+" DOUBLE(11)," +
                                ""+KEY_UNIT+" VACHAR(50)," +
                                ""+KEY_fILEPATH+" VACHAR(255)," +
                                ""+KEY_BOK_ID+" INTEGER(11)," +
                                " FOREIGN KEY("+KEY_BOK_ID+")REFERENCES "+TABLE_BOOK+" ("+KEY_ID+"))";

public static String CATEGORY_CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CATEGORY + "(" +
                                ""+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                                ""+KEY_NAME+" VACHAR(50) " +
                                ")";



//constructor
public BooksDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABSE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

//create
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(BOOK_CREATE_SQL);
    db.execSQL(IMAGE_CREATE_SQL);
    db.execSQL(INGREDIENT_CREATE_SQL);
    db.execSQL(CATEGORY_CREATE_SQL);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE_BOOK);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE_IMAGE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE_INGREDIENT);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE_CATEGORY);
    onCreate(db);

}
```

}

And this is my logcat error edit

```
08-31 08:04:06.957: E/SQLiteLog(1683): (1) no such table: category
08-31 08:04:06.978: D/AndroidRuntime(1683): Shutting down VM
08-31 08:04:06.978: W/dalvikvm(1683): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mutitablesql/com.example.mutitablesql.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: category (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE category
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: category (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE category
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at com.example.mutitablesql.db.BooksDBHelper.onUpgrade(BooksDBHelper.java:80)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:257)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at com.example.mutitablesql.db.BooksDB.<init>(BooksDB.java:23)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at com.example.mutitablesql.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-31 08:04:07.007: E/AndroidRuntime(1683):     ... 11 more
```

before i add a new table from sqlite .It's not have syntax error in my BooksDBHelper Please check it.and tell me which line is syntax error . Thank you

Comment: Maybe you need an extra space between `EXITSbooks` and make the command like :  `DROP TABLE IF EXITS books` ? ( in `onUpgrade` )

Comment: db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS " + TABLE_BOOK); Are you mean like this ??

Comment: `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + TABLE_BOOK + "'");` Does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

**Table creation order is wrong**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CATEGORY_CREATE_SQL);
    db.execSQL(BOOK_CREATE_SQL);
    db.execSQL(IMAGE_CREATE_SQL);
    db.execSQL(INGREDIENT_CREATE_SQL);
}
```